# Reset all primary key fields when row is deleted

Tags: android, sqlite

In my android app I have a methods which deletes a row in a SQLite Database.

Here is the code :

```
public void deleteRow(int id, MyDatabase db, String table) {
        SQLiteDatabase writableDB = db.getWritableDatabase();
        writableDB
                .delete(table, "_id = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(id) });
        writableDB.close();
    }
```

When I execute this method, the row under that id is deleted, and it's content stays empty. I need to replace that row with the next and so on. (Reset primary keys?) Help?

Comment: I guess it's not possible. If you could explain why you need this. may be we can come up with an alternate solution.

Comment: I have a table from which I choose randomly some elements using the ID. So once an element Is chosen, It will be removed, so that It can't be chosen again. When It's deleted I need to recreate new ID's. Example : First I choose element 6, then It deletes him from the table, and the next time if I choose 6, I'll get element 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the actual order of the records does not matter, you can just move the *last* record into the place of the deleted one:

```java
db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + table + " WHERE _id = " + id);
long lastID = DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(db, "SELECT MAX(_id) FROM " + table, null);
if (lastID > id)
    db.execSQL("UPDATE " + table + " SET _id = " + id + " WHERE _id = " + lastID);
```

Comment: what if order matters?

Comment: That is not what this question is about. If you have an actual problem, ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing random selection using the database. You can

If you are displaying it in a

**ListView**: Generate a random number less than the size of your data source and get the element in that index and get the "ID" or "primary key" from the data source and delete the record form you database and update the list.

**Not using any ListView** : You can save the primary key in an ArrayList and generate a random number less than the size of the arrayList and get the "primary key" value at the given index and use primary key to delete the data form the database and update the ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend altering the primary key as it is a unique identifier. 
If you want to display the numbers in a listview, in the adapter used; a cursoradapter, in the bindview method, use int x = getCursor().getPosition() + 1;
Get the view to be used, and set it to use the x-variable of course after converting it to a string...